# How to get the async returns inside a for loop as a stack

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a for loop which is calling an async function each time it calls the async function the async function will return result and i want to push those results in a stack so that i could use the stack to return stack to the dom how can i do that?

```
for(i=1;i<=2;i++){

//I want to put thease responses in a stack.

     const response = await shippingService.createShippingAddress(request);

//I am getting the below in console

     console.log(response);

    }
```

So that i can print the out put.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could u try to do it this way just pushing those responses in stack, & ideally apis error should be handled in a common middleware instead of checking for failure at each request

Comment: I just want to push those responses in a stack. The question is edited.

Comment: What, in this context, is "a stack"? What expectantly do you mean by "return to DOM"? A DOM is typically something you manipulate, when you return something it is usually to a calling function. What is your DOM anyway, you tagged this [tag:node.js] where there is no DOM unless you explicitly create one (usually with one of a variety of third-party libraries).